# do i need to set length for every poco property in Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework-4, code-first, nvarchar

do i need to set length for every poco property in Entity Framework Code First ?  if i dont 
set stringLength or maxlength/minlength for a property , it will be nvarchar(max) ,  how bad is nvarchar(max) ? should i just leave it alone in development stage , and improve it before production ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a Max length for each property where you want to restrict the length. Note that the `nvarchar(max)` data type is different from the `nvarchar(n)` datatype, where `n` is a number from 1-4000. The `max` version that you get when you define no max length is meant for *large* blocks of text, like paragraphs and the like. It can handle extremely large lengths, and so the data is stored separately from the rest of the fields of the record. `nvarchar(n)`, on the other hand, is stored inline with the rest of the rows.

It's probably best to go ahead and set those values as you want now, rather than waiting to do so later. Choose values that are as large as you will ever need, so you never have to increase them. `nvarchar(n)` stores its info efficiently; for example, a `nvarchar(200)` does not necessarily take up 200 characters of space; it only uses enough space to store what is actually put into it, plus a couple extra bytes for saving its length.

So whenever possible, you should set a limit on your entity's text fields.

Comment: The important corollary as far as I have been able to tell is that `nvarchar(max)`, because of its differentness, cannot be used as a key. So anything that might be a key needs a different value.

Answer (score 0):

NVARCHAR - is variable length field. So it consumes only space you need for it. On the other hand NCHAR allocates all the space it requires not on demand as NVARCHAR does.
MSDN advises to use nvarchar when the sizes of the column data entries are probably going to vary considerably.
It's the way to go as for me on the early stages of a project. You can tune it when needed.

Comment: there is a very big difference between nvarchar(#) and nvarchar(max). The former is the field you are talking about. The latter is a different beast, more like the old ntext.

Answer (score 0):

According to the next blog [post](http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsPerfBlog/archive/2008/04/16/ntext-vs-nvarcharmax-in-sql-2005.aspx) nvarchar(max) is not the same as ntext until the actual value size does not reach 4000 symbols (cause limitation is 8K, and widechars use two bytes per char). As far as it hits this size it behaves pretty much the same as ntext. So as for me I don't see any good reason to avoid using nvarchar(max) data type.